# Slutsky's theorem for central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Assume $\sqrt{n}(X_n-X)\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y_n\overset{p}{\to} c$, where $X$ is a random variable and $c$ is a positive constant. Does it hold that $\sqrt{n}(Y_nX_n-cX)\overset{d}{\to} N(0,c^2\sigma^2)$?

Comment: No.  Let $c=1, X=1,Y_n=1+1/n^{1/4}$.

Comment: It would work if $\sqrt{n}|X(Y_n-c)|\rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Comment: @Michael I'm having trouble coming to terms with this. Why would Michael's counterexample work? Doesn't Slutsky's theorem state that the above would hold?

Comment: @MtGlasser : You can try to apply Slutsky's theorem (somehow?) and then see what happens and what goes wrong.

Comment: @mj33  Thanks Michael....

Comment: @Michael You might want to look at the linked question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196191 where I may have said things you could say better